# Possible to determine if a file is present on IPFS by calculating its hash?

Tags: ipfs

If I have a file, and I want to see if it is present on IPFS, is there some obvious way to compute its hash then see if a file is returned from the a url including that hash?

Answer (score 1):

You can check out how a CID is created from a file [here](https://github.com/multiformats/cid) or check out libraries for your languages such as [this one for Rust](https://github.com/multiformats/rust-cid) to encode your file into a CID and compare it with those retrieved from IPFS.

Note that CID is *not* the same as a file's hash. CID is derived from a process called multihash and encoded in base-58 encoding. If you have a hash of a file (like sha-256 or keccak256) that isn't CID and you don't know the file, then it is not possible to retrieve the file from IPFS since the hash or checksum is only useful for validating the file, but not possible to retrieve the file content.

See also: [CID decoding algorithm](https://github.com/multiformats/cid/blob/ef1b2002394b15b1e6c26c30545fd485f2c4c138/README.md#decoding-algorithm)

Comment: Actually the question is, if I only have a hash of the file (I assume Keccak256) but not the file itself, can I find the asset on IPFS.

Comment: The answer still stands. You need to be able to step through how a CID is derived from a file (which isn't just a hash of that file). IPFS uses sha-256 by default as the hashing algorithm so if you have a keccak hash of a content you need to be able to decode that or it's impossible.

See [hashing](https://docs.ipfs.io/concepts/hashing/#important-hash-characteristics)